# Modify hard coded value

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil, hardcoded

How can I change a hard-coded value in the target program I am modifying? The code I want to modify is part of a massive `if` chain. This is the specific section I am looking at:

```
if (this.armor[l].type == 665)
{
    this.maxTime = 150;
}
```

I want to change it so that `this.maxTime = int.MaxValue`. How do I accomplish that? And, if that is not possible, could I target the `if` block and change that? Or can I append some code to the end of the method to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is stored in the `Operand` field of the `Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction` class. The short version is that changing it only requires assigning to that property and saving the assembly.

The long version is that the instruction is likely `OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S` which only takes an sbyte for an `Operand` (-128 to 127) so changing it to int.MaxValue (2147483647) alone will not work. If this is a one off, you can also change the `Opcode` to `OpCodes.Ldc_I4` then you should be good to go.

If you are making many changes then there are a couple of useful extension methods in Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll: `MethodBody.SimplifyMacros` and `MethodBody.OptimizeMacros`.  Simplify will turn short form instructions into their long form and Optimize will do the reverse. The upside of this is that you can search/rewrite your assembly with a reduced instruction set and safely work with instructions that have short forms with a limited argument set. In this case, you would call `SimplifyMacros`, set the `Operand` to the value you want, then call `OptimizeMacro`s to change to the appropriate form.

A tool such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) which will let you look at the original and modified assemblies is invaluable when verifying your work.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the instruction with a different one indicating the value I wanted

Original:
`IL_4361: ldc.i4 150`

New:
`IL_4361: ldc.i4 2147483647`